# Сортировка по произвольному полю

Tags: wordpress

Надо сделать, чтобы товары выводились по убыванию цены. Я пытался сделать. Получилось, что выводит только те товары, которые меньше или равно заданному значению. Как сделать, чтобы они выводились по убыванию?

```
$arr = [
                'id' => '5',
                'meta_query' => [
                    [
                        'key' => 'price',
                        'value' => '10000',
                        'compare' => '<=',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    ]
                ],
                'order' => 'DESC',
             ];

            $recent = new WP_Query($arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
];

$recent = new WP_Query($arr);
```

Comment: спасибо работает)